# How to search in Lucene using symbol synonims?

Tags: java, lucene, full-text-search

I have been using `lucene` for text search in Danish language.

I have tried to implement something similar to "symbols synonym". I searched through `lucene` documentation but cannot find any Analyzer implementation that could help to search like this.

Text should be searched using this symbol synonym map:

    `ø -> [ø, o, oe]
    å -> [å, a, aa]
    æ -> [æ, ae]`

So word `økse` should be found using all following: `økse`, `okse`, `oekse`.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

check out:

- MappingCharFilterFactory doc at https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/charfilter/MappingCharFilterFactory.html
- TokenFilterFactory doc: https://lucene.apache.org/core/6_3_0/analyzers-common/org/apache/lucene/analysis/util/TokenFilterFactory.html

At least one of them, or maybe both, should work